# VSE proxy custom directory

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Imagine you want to edit a documentary film in Blender and you have hundreds of 4K video files. Generating multiple proxies at once is possible now in Blender but challenging, you cannot import 200 files in the VSE and ask Blender to generate proxies, if you do so it will crash. You can only do it little by little and it is very time consuming. The best solution would be to generate proxy files outside of Blender in a batch way and back in Blender link all the high res files to the low res files. The proxy custom directory is made for this but one needs to click on "rebuild proxy" I understand? When you click on "rebuild proxy", although you've already generated proxies, Blender will take ages to connect the high res files in the VSE to the proxies you've already generated. As if Blender is doing the work again. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You can use python scripts to do such batch tasks...

Comment: I honestly cannot imagine editing more than a few minutes in blender's VSE, let alone dealing with 4k footage... My advise would be to use Premiere or FCP or Avid or some dedicated and optimized editing tool.  DaVinci Resolve has great workflows for generating low-res dailies for editing purposes and reconnecting the Hi-Res versions down the line. Any professional tool would cope better with that amount of footage.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't need to rebuild the proxies if you have already made them - so long as they are the right files in the right places, just set the paths, and you should be able to switch to proxy viewing modes.

Comment: Well if I don't rebuild proxies, playback with proxies at 25 or 50% remains poor: around 3 fps.

Comment: I would rebuild proxies if I chose to use an alternate resolution to the one I had already rendered. Also your proxy could be sourced from a render which changes over time due to versioning, this could also require regeneration. But Bassam is right this shouldn't be necessary for video sourced files.  To the issue of slowness, depending on the quantity of strips in the timeline Blender still loads the audio, perhaps this cacheing is causing issues.

Comment: Finally bear in mind that 50% of 4K is still huge and 25% may still be challenging for your system. What quality of proxy are you using? Perhaps you could pull the JPEG compression back?